# passing variable name to dplyr functions when directly get table from MySQL

Tags: r, dplyr

With a dateset stored in MySQL, named "DDD", and 2 variables. like,

```
DDD:
    Var1   Var2
    AAA    1
    AAA    2
    AAC    3
    BBB    4
```

would like to get the rows with "A" in Var1, how should I do?
more like

```
library(dplyr)
con <- src_mysql(dbname="DDD")
Result <- con %%>> tbl("DDD") %>% filter(grep("A",Var1)) ## which is not correct
```

Which I know is not correct, how can I just get the variable name and operate as if the database is in RAM, like

```
Result <- filter(grep("A",DDD$Var1))
```

Yet, since the data is directly collected from MySQL, then it has no name until the data is collected, and it is also impossible for me to put the whole dataset in RAM, simply because it is way to big.
many thanks

Comment: If `df` is your dataframe, `df[grep("A", df$Var1), ]`.

Comment: Thanks. @RonakShah. The question is that I have no idea about the name of "df". SInce it is directly collected from MySQL. I have to name it before I can use it. Then it can't be expressed in chain(%>%) situation.

Comment: Maybe I make it way too complicated. My purpose is to get the rows with certain "words" in the certain column. so the process shall be like (1) connect to db, (2) open the table (3) find the right rows under certain condition (4) and get the right rows. How can I do this? Please advise.

Comment: the output of `grep` is a numeric index while `filter` takes logical.  You may need `grepl` i.e.  `tbl("DDD") %>% filter(grepl("A",Var1))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun however, it can't be explained to SQL, so doesn't work. the error message is 'could not run statement: FUNCTION wifi.GREPL does not exist'

Comment: Okay, may be it is a SQL issue.  In that case can you try with `slice(grep("A", Var1))`

Comment: thanks, just did a quick test, and gave err msg again. will look into it soon. Many thanks, @akrun